# Question about closure.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This seems like a simple question but for some reason I cannot wrap my head around it. Let $V$ be a fixed subset of $\textbf{R}^n$ and let $A$ be a subset of $V$.

I am trying to show that $V\cap \overline{V\setminus A}=V\cap\overline{\mathbf{R}^n\setminus A}$. It is clear that $V\cap \overline{V\setminus A}\subseteq V\cap\overline{\mathbf{R}^n\setminus A}$, but I am having trouble with the other direction. Specifically, if $x\in V\cap\overline{\mathbf{R}^n\setminus A}$, then $x$ is a limit point of $\mathbf{R}^n\setminus A$. How can I show that it is a limit point of $V\setminus A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true. Take $A=V$ for example. Or take $V=[0,2]$ and $A=[1,2]$.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks!